# How to convert a XZ compression output to a NSString?

Tags: nsstring, objective-c++, stdstring, xz

I've successfully set up a small XZ compressor which returns a std::string that contains the compressed output. To process the result I need to "convert" the std::string to a NSString. Unfortunately there are (encoding?) problems:

Even though "abc" is not a good example it shows the difficulty pretty good:

```
NSString *text = [_text string]; // Length is 3

std::string content = xz_compress([text UTF8String]); // Length is 60

NSString *convertedContent = [NSString stringWithCString:content.c_str() encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// convertedContent is (null) and 0 characters long
```

Using NSUnicodeStringEncoding makes the NSString at least 2 characters long but they don't match the ones from std::string.

My questions:

- Is this way possible / the preferable way (already unsure about that)?
- If so: What encoding do I need to use?

Thanks in advance!

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that xz_compress output is binary data. So, why don't you try and use `NSData` `dataWithBytes:length:` method? Possibly you could also try with `string::data()` instead of `string::c_str` for the same reason:

```
NSData* convertedContent = [NSData dataWithBytes:content.data() length:content.length()];
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! But am I still able to "add" data to the NSData? I would like to have a JSON file that also holds this compressed data.